# Terminal multiplexer with mouse support

Tags: kubuntu

I am looking for a terminal multiplexer. I know about tmux. It is great but it has one disadvantage. It doesn't make possible copy/paste selected text with mouse ( and it doesn't support right click mouse). So, what other multiplexers are there, and what are the advantages/disadvantages to them?

Maybe terminator meets my expectations?

Comment: mouse support in terminals is really specific to the applications you are running. There are several ways to implement it and this results in gaps in the coverage of mouse support in different terminal multiplexers so it would help if you where clearer about what you are running.

Comment: But, note that for example yakuake make it possible to copy and paste with a mouse.